# Rails: Shopify integration withouth a shopify app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I'm going to use the https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app Gem

I want to be able to pull the orders into my rails app using the Shopify API.

The question I have is it possible to connect to a Shopify store without creating a Shopify app, like the eBay model?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the answer is no. To do anything with the API you need to send the store's OAuth token, and you can't get that unless the store installs your app.

Comment: That's what i had assumed., this link http://gavinballard.com/shopify-oauth-flow-for-dummies/ provides a good starting point

Answer (score 0):

Shopify is a hosted solution.
It only allows communication from other apps through an API, and only if your app is run/initiated from their environment with authention tokens (even though your app's real code will be hosted on your server)

Answer (score 0):

Since the following works, I don't see why not?

```
curl https://${api_user}:${api_key}@${your_store}.com/admin/orders.json?ids=${order_id}
```

Source: https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/order#index

Just use your favourite http lib/gem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Shopify private app which will provide you the secret and passwords and you can assign the needful resources you want to use and you can easily pull data from shopify without any public app
https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/apps/private-apps#generate-credentials-from-the-shopify-admin

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with GraphQL. [Here's a codepen](https://%20https://codepen.io/kenput3r/pen/jOWKOYb) I use often (in javascript, not ruby, sorry) to quickly test if it's working.

Just replace the contents of the endpoint and query variables with your store and [query](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-graphql/2022-01/queries/orders).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. The OAuth is essential for a public app with an interface within Shopify. If you don't plan on creating a guided user interface you can connect to the admin or gql api with just the keys.